# How to force my app to the front

Tags: android

I have developed an android app that uses a timer with a call back.  When a specific criteria has been satisfied, the app either rings or vibrates the phone depending on user settings.  It will continue to ring until the user acknowledges an alert box.  This all works fine.  However, if the user has brought another app to the front then he may not realize it is my app causing the phone to ring and re-open it.  Is there a way I can force my App to the front or at least the Alert Message to be on top of anything else?

Comment: You should **never** force your way into a user's workflow like this.

Comment: Actually this was suggested by a user so perhaps you might serve better by simply answering the question rather than making snap judgements.  Since the user may be in a noisy environment and may not notice a simple quick notification, is not exactly appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

Notifications are your friend. They wont interrupt a users workflow and with the new JellyBean apis you can put actions and other dynamic components in them.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of doing that, you could just use a notification with a specific ringtone once it has been sent instead of annoying the user this way.